# Codeigniter 3: load a mobile specific view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have put together a CRUD application with CI 3. I am trying to load a mobile specific template (view) for the homepage. For this purpose I have:

1) Loaded the user_agent library:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'user_agent');
```

2) Created a directory called *mobile* in the views directory and a home.php view file inside it.

3) The Home controller looks like this:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() {
    $this->load->model('Customer');
    $customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers();
    if ($this->agent->is_browser()) {
     $this->load->view('home', ['records'=>$customers]);
    } else {
     $this->load->view('mobile/home', ['records'=>$customers]);
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Failed opening required 'includes/header.php'
```

NOTE: At the top of my view files I have:

```
<?php require "includes/header.php"; ?>
```

The *includes* directory is *directly in the views* directory so I believe the first thing to do is **use the application's root** in the path above.

How do I do that?

Comment: is "includes/header.php" under CI view folder?

Comment: Yes, "includes/header.php" is under CI view directory.

Comment: then try $this->load->view("includes/header"); instead of require "includes/header.php";

Comment: Also when passing data through view have look at this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#creating-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$this->load->view("includes/header");` instead of require `includes/header.php;`